# Why are the equal values of this program not printing?

Tags: python, list, comparison

I'm creating two functions, one that will return a list of lists: the first element in the list contains a list of letters that appear in a collection of strings and the second element contains a list of their counts. The second is iterating through the list of list returned from the first function, finding the largest count and returning it as the variable large. I'm trying to compare the letter counts returned from the first function with the largest number returned from the second function to print the equal values. For some reason, the equal values are not printing and i'm not sure why? Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
def mkdict():
    """ This function is creating a dictionary of letters and their frequency."""

    for string in strings:
        for letter in string:
            if letter in array[0]:
                pos = array[0].index(letter)
                array[1][pos] = array[1][pos] + 1
            else:
                array[0].append(letter)
                array[1].append(1)
     return array
  # Printing this function returns: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'z'], [5, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6]]

def getlar():
    list = mkdict()
    large = list[1][0]
    for item in list[1]:
        if item > large:
            large = item
    return large
    # Printing this function returns: 6.

for num in mkdict()[1]:
    if num == getlar():
        print num
# This loop should print : 6 three times but it isn't.
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `num` and `getlar()` instead of comparing them and then conditionally printing something? I suspect those values aren't what you expected them to be.

Comment: And is this code just a frequency counter? You might look into the `collections.Counter` class and the `max()` function.

Comment: Why aren't you using a Python dictionary for the dictionary, instead of an array of arrays?

Comment: Where do you initialize `array`?

Comment: If you initialize it outside `mkdict`, then every time you call `mkdict` it adds to the counts, they don't start from `0`. And you're calling `mkdict()` every time you call `getlar()`, so it keeps increasing the counts.

Comment: I guess @Barmar has pointed out the root cause - array should have been initialized in mkdict.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone. I do have two other solutions one using the counter module and the other using Python a dictionary but I also want to try with using an "array".  I'll take a look at using max().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't initialize `array` in `mkdict()`, so every time you call it you add to the counts in the global `array` variable (which you haven't shown, but it obviously has to exist or you'd get an error). You should use a local variable.

```
def mkdict():
    """ This function is creating a dictionary of letters and their frequency."""
    array = []
    for string in strings:
        for letter in string:
            if letter in array[0]:
                pos = array[0].index(letter)
                array[1][pos] = array[1][pos] + 1
            else:
                array[0].append(letter)
                array[1].append(1)
     return array
```

Also, you shouldn't call `mkdict()` every time you call `lar()`. The counts aren't going to change, so you should just call it once, save the result in a variable, and pass that to `getlar()`.

```
def getlar(list):
    large = list[1][0]
    for item in list[1]:
        if item > large:
            large = item
    return large

counts = mkdict()
for num in counts[1]:
    if num == getlar(counts):
        print num
```

Actually, calling `getlar()` repeatedly is also unnecessary, since the largest isn't going to change.

```
counts = mkdict()
largest = getlar(counts)
for num in counts[1]:
    if num = largest:
        print num
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I forgot to include my array variable in this post. My variable array = [[], []] was defined global and not locally.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using global variables. Use local variables, function parameters, and return values.